# how to programmatically select the date/time and title for Event Kit calendar

Tags: xcode, eventkit

Below is my code. currently on a button click it opens up the calendar so the user can add events.  How do I pass or preselect a date and title for the user when the event calendar opens up?

Heres my code.

```
 -(IBAction) createEvent{
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

EKEventEditViewController * controller =[[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
controller.eventStore = eventStore;
controller.editViewDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController: controller animated:YES]'



}

-(void) eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController *) controller didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventEditViewAction)action{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign an event to the EKEventEditViewController. You fill in your details into the event object.

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *event = [store eventWithIdentifier:@"some identifier"];
if(!event)
{
    event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
    event.startDate = someDate;
    event.endDate = someEndDate;
    event.location = someLocationString;
    event.availability = EKEventAvailabilityBusy;
    event.title = @"Title here";
}
EKEventEditViewController *ekVC = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
ekVC.event = event;
ekVC.editViewDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:ekVC animated:YES];
```